# How ctrl+c and ctrl+d trigger the stdout 'data' event of a spawned child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, shell, child-process

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const child = spawn('wc')

process.stdin.pipe(child.stdin)

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`child stdout:\n ${data}`)
})
```

The `child.stdout.on('data'...` will execute when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> under parent process , 
Why not <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>?

**Note:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> kill a process with the signal `SIGINT`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> the application is notified that the end of the file has been reached.

ref: [ctrl+d vs ctrl+c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-signal-the-end-of-stdin-input/16338#16338?newreg=f35c116d30dc43db84d84467e544967b)